# Creating dataframe from xml

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have an xml that I want to parse out and create a dataframe. What I have been trying so far is something like this:

```
all_dicts = []
fields = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7']
for i in root.findall('.//item'):
    d = {}
    for j in product.findall('.//subitems'):
        for k in j.findall('.//subitem'):
            if k.attrib['name'] in fields:
                d[k.attrib['name']] = k.text

    all_dicts.append(d)
```

This gives me a list of dictionaries that I can easily do pd.DataFrame(all_dicts) to get what I want. However, the `subitems` tend to have multiple sub-elements that have the same `name`. For example, each `subitem` could have multiple times where `k.attrib['name'] == f1`, so it adds an item to the dictionary with the same key and therefore just overwrites the previous value when I need all of them. Is there a way to create such as data frame easily?

Answer (score 1):

- Use [`dict.get`](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/#dgetltkeygt-ltdefaultgt) to check if the key exists

  - If the key does not exist, add it as a list
  - If the key does exist, append to the list
- Without a comprehensive example of the xml, I can't offer a more detailed example.

```py
all_dicts = []
fields = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7']
for i in root.findall('.//item'):
    d = dict()
    for j in product.findall('.//subitems'):
        for k in j.findall('.//subitem'):
            n = k.attrib['name']
            if n in fields:
                if d.get(n) == None:  # check if key exist
                    d[n] = [k.text]  # add key as a list 
                else:
                    d[n].append(k.text)  # append to list

    all_dicts.append(d)
```

- Alternatively, only add the `dict` value as a list, if the field is `'f1'`.

```py
all_dicts = []
fields = ['f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7']
for i in root.findall('.//item'):
    d = dict()
    for j in product.findall('.//subitems'):
        for k in j.findall('.//subitem'):
            n = k.attrib['name']
            if n in fields and n == 'f1':  # if field is 'f1' add list
                if d.get(n) == None:  # check if key exist
                    d[n] = [k.text]  # add key as a list
                else:
                    d[n].append(k.text)  # append to list
            elif n in fields:  # if field isn't 'f1' just add the text
                d[n] = k.text

    all_dicts.append(d)
```